# Rewriting old Unity shader to Universal Render Pipeline (Shader Graph)

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I had previously written a few custom shaders for my game, but now I want to upgrade to the Universal Render Pipeline in Unity and I'm struggling to recreate an old shader with the new Shader Graph. How would I do this given the code below?

The shader is applied to a tilemap; it assigns the appropriate color to each tile (is it grass, water, or sand?). It is based on a set of starting and ending colors given through a script for each of the tile types (grass, sand, water) and the number of steps between those colors (_StartCols, _EndCols).

I have tried implementing the 'Tiling and Offset' node to no avail; I cannot change the colors and get the colors I want. My current version of Unity is Unity 2019.3, and I'm using the Shader Graph to try to recreate this old shader.

Here is the code for the old shader:

```
Shader "Custom/Terrain"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex ("Albedo (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
        LOD 200

        CGPROGRAM
        // Physically based Standard lighting model, and enable shadows on all light types
        #pragma surface surf Standard fullforwardshadows

        // Use shader model 3.0 target, to get nicer looking lighting
        #pragma target 3.0

        sampler2D _MainTex;

        struct Input
        {
            float2 uv_MainTex;
        };

        float4 _StartCols[3];
        float4 _EndCols[3];

        void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutputStandard o)
        {
            int colIndex = (int)IN.uv_MainTex.x;
            float t = IN.uv_MainTex.y;
            o.Albedo = lerp(_StartCols[colIndex],_EndCols[colIndex],t);
        }
        ENDCG
    }
    FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```

I have not received any error messages so far; however, the colors are way off given the shader graph I have configured currently. I do know that it is not complete at the moment, because I am currently stuck at this point.

Here is the result I previously had before changing render pipelines:
http://prntscr.com/p0xcwl

Here is what I have now:
http://prntscr.com/p0xdvf

This is what my Shader Graph currently looks like:
http://prntscr.com/p0xfhh

If you need any more information, please don't hesitate to ask!